# Finding the max temperature for a given day in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

My tables:

```
hourly_weather                 electrical_readings
----------------               -----------------------
meter | time_read | temp       meter | time      | kwh
----------------               -----------------------
1       1316044800  55         1       1316136250  19.24
1       1316138400  56         1       1316044320  18.29
(...)                          (...)
```

I want to retrieve two important values from this data:

1) I want the total KW for a given day

2) And I want the max temperature for that day

The query I'm using takes WAYYYY too long to run but I can't think of another way to do it. Like, several hours for 100,000 rows of data in both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * , SUM(kwh) AS sumkwh, 
           DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( r.time_read ) ) AS datex, 
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( r.time_read ) ) ) AS datey, 
           (
               SELECT MAX( temp )
               FROM hourly_weather hw
               WHERE hw.meter = 1
                 AND time_read >= datey
                 AND time_read < datey + 86400
           ) AS temp
FROM electrical_readings r
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY datex
) as t1
WHERE t1.temp != '';
```

Comment: try running the query without the outer select; what's the speed gain? It seems to me it would already increase your performance. Another solution would probably be to store those two important values for the set day during a cron, right after that day. Those values won't change (or will they)?

Comment: Removing the outer select has almost no effect on query runtime.

Comment: If I remove the AND time_read >= datey clauses on the subquery, it removes 99% of the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(r.time_read)) AS datex, 
  SUM(r.kwh) AS sumkwh, MAX(hw.temp) AS temp
FROM electrical_readings r
LEFT OUTER JOIN hourly_weather hw
  ON DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(r.time_read)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(hw.time_read)) 
  AND hw.meter = 1
WHERE r.id = 1
GROUP BY datex
HAVING temp IS NOT NULL
```

This will still be a problem for performance, because this uses expressions for the joins.  It therefore has to read *every* row of both tables, to evaluate the expressions before it can tell if the join is satisfied.

It would therefore be much better if you could add an extra column to both tables for the date (with no time) and index those columns.

```
ALTER TABLE electrical_readings ADD COLUMN date_read DATE, ADD KEY (date_read);
UPDATE electrical_readings SET date_read = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_read));

ALTER TABLE hourly_weather ADD COLUMN date_read DATE, ADD KEY (date_read);
UPDATE hourly_weather SET date_read = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_read));

SELECT r.date_read, 
  SUM(r.kwh) AS sumkwh, MAX(hw.temp) AS temp
FROM electrical_readings r
LEFT OUTER JOIN hourly_weather hw
  ON r.date_read = hw.date_read 
  AND hw.meter = 1
WHERE r.id = 1
GROUP BY r.date_read
HAVING temp IS NOT NULL
```

In any case, adding `SELECT *` to either of these queries is not a good idea, because the results will be arbitrary.

---

Re your comment, sorry, the sum is multiplied by the number of matching rows in hourly_weather.

We can compensate by doing the aggregate for hourly_weather in a *derived table* subquery.

```
SELECT r.date_read, 
  SUM(r.kwh) AS sumkwh, hw.temp
FROM electrical_readings r
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT date_read, MAX(temp) AS temp
  FROM hourly_weather
  WHERE meter = 1
  GROUP BY date_read) AS hw
    ON r.date_read = hw.date_read 
WHERE r.id = 1
GROUP BY r.date_read
HAVING temp IS NOT NULL
```

It would be good to create an index on hourly_weather:

```
ALTER TABLE hourly_weather ADD KEY (date_read, meter, temp);
```

Comment: Big improvement on what I had before. Cheers.

Comment: This isn't quite working as expected, it seems to be making the sumkwh vastly greater than it should be. If I remove the left outer join, there's no issue.

Comment: I think I've found the issue, there are 24 readings for each day in the "hourly_weather" table. If I divide the sumkwh your query gives me by 24, I get the actual sumkwh. Anyway to remedy this without something so arbitrary?

Comment: I just went back to subquerying as part of the SELECT and its faster and works.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be simpler to calculate both values in separate queries and then joining the resulting data sets. You can even define temporary variables and tables to make things easier:

```
# Temp variables for the dates
set @t0 = cast('2013-02-01' as date);
set @t1 = cast('2013-02-02' as date);

# Temporary table 1: Sum of KWH
create temporary table temp_sum_kw
    select 
        date(from_unixtime(timeread)) as `date`, sum(KWH) as sum_kwh
    from 
        electrical_readings
    where 
        timeread >= unix_timestamp(@t0) and timeread < unix_timestamp(date_add(@t1, interval +1 day))
    group by 
        date(from_unixtime(timeread));
alter table temp_sum_kw
    add index idx_date(`date`);

# Temporary table 2: Max temp
create temporary table temp_max_temperature
    select 
        date(from_unixtime(timeread)) as `date`, max(temp) as max_temp
    from 
        hourly_weather
    where 
        (timeread >= @t0 and timeread < date_add(@t1, interval +1 day))
        and meter = 1
    group by 
        date(from_unixtime(timeread));
alter table temp_max_temperature
    add index idx_date(`date`);

# Put it all together
select 
    m.*, t.max_temp
from
    temp_sum_kw as m
    inner join temp_max_temperature as t on m.`date` = t.`date`;
```

The reason for using the `where` condition `timeread >= @t0 and timeread < date_add(@t1, interval +1 day)` is to include everything that happens until the last moment of `@t1`.

Hope this helps you

Comment: +1 just for going through all the effort to help someone to write such a long query

Comment: This would be great if I only wanted the max temperature for a single day. I want to see 4/1/2013-22deg, 4/2/2012-24deg, 4/3/2012-18deg. Etc, etc. My query is finding the max temperature for all of the days that electrical readings were taken.

Comment: So you're saying query for two result sets and just loop over them with PHP to combine them? Doable but I was hoping there was an elegant SQL solution. That's a lot of php array sorting and whatnot and I wouldn't expect it to be faster than my current query honestly :/

Comment: @ChrisG. Sometimes *elegant* is not the same as *fast*. Give it a try, it maybe faster. I've found that "divide and conquer" frequently gives faster solutions (at least in my experience). If you want to get the data for a single day, then simply use `timeread >= unix_timestamp(@t0) and timeread < unix_timestamp(date_add(@t0, interval +1 day))`. By the way, I made a mistake in the query... forgot to use `unix_timestamp()`. I'm editing that right now

Comment: +1'd for effort and education, but the accepted answer solved my issue at the expense of some additional writing to the db.